# PYPDF2 - Extracting all pages and converting to CSV

Tags: python, pypdf

I am new to Python and was trying to extract data from PDF into a CSV file and below is the code I am using:

```
import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd

file = 'Test Slip.pdf'

lines = []

with pdfplumber.open(file) as pdf:
    pages = pdf.pages
    for page in pdf.pages:
        text = page.extract_text()
        for line in text.split('\n'):
            print(line)

df = pd.DataFrame(lines)

df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

I can see the entire text in my terminal which is great. However, the CSV file is coming blank. Can anyone point out the error in my code?

Comment: Does your `print(line)` statement actually print something ?

Comment: @ibi0tux 'I can see the entire text in my terminal which is great'

Answer (score 2):

you forget to append string `line` to list `lines`.
The issue is that the variable `lines` is always equal to `[]`
Try with this code:

```
import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd

file = 'Test Slip.pdf'

lines = []

with pdfplumber.open(file) as pdf:
    pages = pdf.pages
    for page in pdf.pages:
        text = page.extract_text()
        for line in text.split('\n'):
            lines.append(line)
            print(line)

df = pd.DataFrame(lines)

df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its coming out perfectly. I will try my hand at formatting the entire thing now.